# How to wire a Service that depends on more than its own Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a standard Spring Boot (with Spring Web and Spring Data) Rest Web service and got into this situation.

If for example I have two entities:

- User
- Team

And they have a Many-to-many releationship. How would their services look?

Option 1:

- UserService depends on UserRepository
- TeamService depends on TeamRepository and **UserRepository**

Option 2:

- UserService depends on UserRepository
- TeamService depends on TeamRepository and **UserService**

I was thinking Option 2 because every repository is interfaced through its respective service, but the following problem comes from that:

If I want the services to only expose DTOs and need an entity  of User inside my TeamService for Many-to-many to work using Hibernate(I need a reference not only id). I have to either do workarounds or expose an entity from the UserService.

What would be the more clear solution or am I getting something mixed up in my logic?

Edit:

Some context:

If i need a method like addUserToTeam(Integer userId, Integer teamId) inside TeamService I would need to get the user entity by id in order to add it to the team list of users.

Comment: Why does teamService need to depend on either? Their functionality would be mutually exclusive.

Comment: If i need a method like addUserToTeam(Integer userId, Integer teamId) inside TeamService I would need to get the user entity by id in order to add it to the team list of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It depends`. Depends on your business use-cases .. rules...

Between `Team` and `User` is there some kind of owner ?

Is your business required to create a team before push users inside ? or let users been created in an independant way ?

Maybe when you have to create a user you have to assign him a team .. maybe not..

Imagine you have to create a `Team` before add `Users` into you can now considered `Team` as an aggregate concept (look at Domain driven design aggregate).

A DDD aggregate is a cluster of domain objects that can be treated as a single unit.

And so going with these objects :

- Entities/ValueObjects  : Team , User
- Repository : TeamRepository
- Service : TeamService

So "in this case" no need for `USerService or UserRepo`. Each time you want to add/delete/update a user you will do through the `Team`object/aggregate. And so registration of a new `User` will be done through

```java
team.addUser(user);
teamRepository.update(team team)
```

If now both concepts are totally independent you could see them as 2 separate aggregates and both will have their own repository.

Concerning the service as team and users are related concepts having 2 services could be overkill.

A single service to maintain lifecyle and consistency between `Team` and `Users` sounds more suitable.

So :

- Entity/VO : Team, User
- Repo  : TeamRepository, UserRepository
- Service : XXXService (XXX replaced by the noun of your choice)

I just say that `one service = one aggregate` is not a rule... Services are facade and facade can wrap a domain model composed of multiple aggregates.`Keep cohesion high` is the rule.

Comment: Interesting but in my case User and Team are two separete aggregates which can exist on their own. And I have operations which relate to business logic with users in the UserService and with teams in TeamService. The owner of the releationship you could say is Team because a team consists of users. Team is not required to have users and User is not required to be in a team.

Comment: actually it will depend on the number of available operations. If it is a simple CRUD just having a single facade with less than 10 operations could make the job without introduces bad coupling or less cohesion.. Think pragmatism

Comment: I am not sure I understand you (I know what a facade is). Can you elaborate with an example or a more descriptive explanation

Comment: I'm just say that `one service = one aggregate` is not a rule...  Services are facade and facade can wrap a domain model composed of multiple aggregate. Keep `cohesion high` is the rule.

Comment: Can you just add that last comment into your answer to make it clearer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The repositories are bound to the database structures.

The services are related to the business logic that you need.

For example a UserService could include methods to get Teams or Users if you thing that belongs to the same business logic.

Comment: But that way I lose the idea of a UserService controlling how to save/update/... Users from UserRepository because I will have other UserRepository access from TeamService.

Comment: Services are not CRUD's remember the responsability that each layer has. Repository, persist and retrieves the data. Services are business logic. Imagine a business method called createUser() but could be also getAllUsersFromTeam(teamName). It depends a lot of where you put the limits. But this concept that the service has only the save/update/... as you said only made that you push the logic into the next layer. That's not a good idea.

Comment: Yes services are not only CRUD but I still feel like I shouldnt expose the repository outside of UserService.

Comment: You don't need to expose outside of the UserService, but remember the general rule, repositories connect to services not to other layers and services call repositories, never other services.

Comment: That is not what I have been taught. Services form bussines logic by calling other services that define bussines logic on different entities/domain objects

Comment: `The services are related to the business logic that you need.` In a simple system it could be true by having User and Team as `anemic objects` and services implements as `transactional scripts` with some few logic. But in main case business logic should be concentrate inside your domain model (aka entities and value objects) and not inside services... Think OO

Comment: Yes that is if I wouldn't want to have anemic entities. For this application my entities are anemic and I prefer them to stay this way. In my case bussines logic is inside the services.

Comment: as I said if your business logic is simple it is an acceptable choice. As your maintainance cost is cheap... everything's ok.